# Parse Cloud - fetch thumbnail from URL

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my `ParseCloud-function` I would like to retrieve a Thumbnail (JPG/PNG) from the URL and save it as a `ParseFile`.

**ParseCloud-function**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("statusDone",function(request,response)
{
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var doneObjectId = request.params.doneObject;

s_status      = request.params.s_status;
s_message     = request.params.s_message;
s_link        = request.params.s_link;

var StatusObject = Parse.Object.extend("Status");
var sObject = StatusObject .createWithoutData( doneObjectId );
sObject .set("isDone", true);
sObject .set("link", s_link);
sObject .set("message", s_message);
sObject .set("statusColor", s_statusColor);

...

}
```

Here, I would like to fetch a thumbnail for `link` and save it as a `ParseFile`

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to use Parse.Cloud.httpRequest inside your cloud code, execute a call to s_link from there get the result and save it in Parse.File here is some code snippets:

```
 Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: s_link,
      headers: {
          // in case you need request headers
      }
  }).then(function(res) {
    // here you get the result from here you can create your Parse.File in the following way (from parse js DOCS).
    // 1. create file with bytes
    // var bytes = [ 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xCA, 0xFE ];
    // var file = new Parse.File("file_name}", bytes,"{content_type}");
    // 2. create with base64 string 
    // var base64 = "V29ya2luZyBhdCBQYXJzZSBpcyBncmVhdCE=";
    // var file = new Parse.File("myfile.txt", { base64: base64 });
  });
```

Comment: If I include this in the cloud function are there chances of the function being timed out and returning an error?